# Django POST json to frontend server

Tags: json, django, post

I have Django Server that contains class user,
I can POST and GET data (JSON) on it from client side.
What I need to do now is to POST this data from my server to another and GET successful response.

How can I do it, the best answer is described example, as I'm really newbie.

The server on another side is already done to get my data and then add it to database and send me response.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why yo need this, but you can take a look to "Python request" library.

You have a lot of examples here, like a POST request:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/